# Analytic method of solving $\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\frac{\sin(2x)^x(\ln(\sin(x))+\ln(\cos(x))-x(\tan(x)-\cot(x)))}{2^x}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I stumbled upon the following integral which evaluates to -1. However I cannot find a way to solve this analytically, any ideas?
$$\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\frac{\sin(2x)^x(\ln(\sin(x))+\ln(\cos(x))-x(\tan(x)-\cot(x)))}{2^x}\,dx=-1$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

$$I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sin x\cos x)^x(\ln(\sin x)+\ln(\cos x)+x(\cot x-\tan x))dx$$ 
$$=\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{x(\ln(\sin x)+\ln(\cos x))}(\ln(\sin x)+\ln(\cos x)+x(\cot x-\tan x))dx$$

Now substitute $t=e^{x(\ln(\sin x)+\ln(\cos x))}$ and see what you get.